# Pyplot colormap line by line

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm beginning with plotting on python using the very nice pyplot. I aim at showing the evolution of two series of data along time. Instead of doing a casual plot of data function of time, I'd like to have a scatter plot (data1,data2) where the time component is shown as a color gradient.

In my two column file, the time would be described by the line number. Either written as a 3rd column in the file either using the intrinsic capability of pyplot to get the line number on its own.

Can anyone help me in doing that ?

Thanks a lot.

Nicolas

Comment: please post your  code for to provide us with a lead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When plotting using [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) you can pass a third array via the keyword argument `c`. This array can choose the colors that you want your scatter points to be. You then also pick an appropriate colormap from [`matplotlib.cm`](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) and assign that with the `cmap` keyword argument.

This toy example creates two datasets `data1` and `data2`. It then also creates an array `colors`, an array of continual values equally spaced between 0 and 1, and with the same length as `data1` and `data2`. It doesn't need to know the "line number", it just needs to know the total number of data points, and then equally spaces the colors.

I've also added a `colorbar`. You can remove this by removing the `plt.colorbar()` line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np


N = 500
data1 = np.random.randn(N)
data2 = np.random.randn(N)
colors = np.linspace(0,1,N)

plt.scatter(data1, data2, c=colors, cmap=cm.Blues)

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]